# How to detect outgoing calls when app is in the background on iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios5

I need to detect the state of a call in an iPhone app, when my app is in the background. I need to do something when the state of the call is outgoing.

Is this possible? If this is possible how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible. `CTCallCenter` gives some info in the state of a call but you'll only get those notifications when your app is active.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. Note that I wrote 'active'. An app does not stay active in the background for long.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`CTCallCenter Class Reference`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html) and [`CTCall Class Reference`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590). The available states are defined as:

### CTCallCenter

```
callEventHandler
```

### CTCall

```
callState
```

### Cellular Call States

```
CTCallStateDialing  
CTCallStateIncoming  
CTCallStateConnected  
CTCallStateDisconnected
```